# Using jaxws plugin to generate Java classes from WSDL that will implement common interface via bindigs

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, wsimport

I have wsdl file with following types:

```
<xs:complexType name="someName">
....
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="someOtherName">
....
</xs:complexType>
```

What I am trying to achieve is for this types to implement common interface

```
public interface Test {
//methods that already exist in the types
}
```

To achieve this, I created binding file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxws:bindings
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc inheritance"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        wsdlLocation="my_wsdl.wsdl">

    <enableWrapperStyle>true</enableWrapperStyle>
    <enableAsyncMapping>false</enableAsyncMapping>
    <jaxws:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='someName']">
        <inheritance:implements>com.mycompany.package.Test</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

and also configured plugin:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jaxws-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.6.4</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>wsdl</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsimport</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <xjcArgs>
                                    <xjcArg>-Xinheritance</xjcArg>
                                    <xjcArg>-Xequals</xjcArg>
                                    <xjcArg>-XtoString</xjcArg>
                                </xjcArgs>
                                <genJWS>true</genJWS>
                                <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/soap</bindingDirectory>
                                <bindingFiles>
                                    <bindingFile>binding.xjb</bindingFile>
                                </bindingFiles>
                                <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
                                <xdebug>true</xdebug>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <wsdlUrls>
                                    <wsdlUrl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/soap/my_wsdl.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                                </wsdlUrls>
                                <sourceDestDir>target/generated-sources/soap</sourceDestDir>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
```

The flags

```
<xjcArg>-Xequals</xjcArg>
<xjcArg>-XtoString</xjcArg>
```

are taken into account, and my generated classes have following signature:

```
public class SomeName implements ToString, Equals{...}
```

but, the -Xinheritance option, even though taken into account (before I added dependency on jaxb2-basics, it was complaining about unknown option) is not having any effect on the code generation.
the XPath in bindings is correct, and binding is taken into account
for example, if instead of

```
<inheritance:implements>com.mycompany.package.Test</inheritance:implements>
```

I provide:

```
<jaxb:class name="changedName"/>
```

class will be generated with changed name, but they will still not implement the interface that I want.

Do you have any ideas what is wrong?
I suspect issue is with binding file, but I cannot pin-point exact location.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow this [wiki page](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB2-Inheritance-Plugin) about the inheritence plugin in the official repository.

From what I see the main difference is the jaxws/jaxb prefix used in bindings.

You can also try to add extra debug in your maven build using `-X -e` options to see debug output during classes generation.

You can follow this [migration guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Tools-Migration-Guide) on how to get the latest version of the jaxb-tools which is now all merged into the same location.

If it still doesnt work, come back and I'll look deeper, and if necessary, I'll create an issue in jaxb-tools' github repo

**EDIT**

After debugging the `wsimport`, it seems that the `extensionBindingPrefixes` attribute you can set in `jaxb:bindings` is not taken into account when defined in `jaxws:bindings` and it seems to be by design according XSD

> A binding compiler only processes this attribute when it occurs on an instance of xs:schema element. The value of this attribute is a whitespace-separated list of namespace prefixes. The namespace bound to each of the prefixes is designated as a customization declaration namespace.

If you want to use bindings to customize the output with `extensionBindingPrefixes` plugins, you need to externalize the XSD into is own file and then use the standard `jaxb:bindings` process.

The section of `wsdl:types` should look like the following :

```xml
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.cleverbuilder.com/BookService/" schemaLocation="my_xsd.xsd" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
```

And the `my_xsd.xsd` file would contain the schema definition elements.

This also explains why defining it inline the WSDL makes it work (since the `extensionBindingPrefixes` has been defined on `xs:schema`)

Comment: I still couldn't make it work.
I decided to instead add this inside wsdl as xs:annotationn inside the complexType, and after that it generated classes correctly.
https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB2-Inheritance-Plugin
but no idea why with bindings it wouldn't have an effect.

Comment: This is strange, could you create an issue in github with minimal reproducer so I could investigate ?

Comment: sure, I've created issue:
https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/issues/471
and also repo with empty spring project and example wsdl/binding/interface:
https://github.com/Blomex/jaxws-generating-classe-mre

Comment: Perfect :D I'll keep you updated ;)

Comment: I've seen in the example that you're using SpringBoot 3.x but stick to jaxb-api 2.3. Is it normal and is the same for your project or is it a mistake in creating the sample ?

Comment: Updated answer to explain how it works 